# Complements and adjuncts

Tags: syntactic-analysis, linguistics, complements, adjuncts

> Paul Austen’s novel sold immediately to the author’s eager readers.

In the above sentence, which part is the *complement* and which is the *adjunct*? I am confused as to whether the adjunct should be *immediately* or *eager readers*.

Comment: A noun adjunct, which is the tag you've used, can only be a noun, so it can't be *immediately*. Do you just mean adjuncts in general?

Comment: Yes, I'm concerned with adjuncts in general.

Comment: Whose terminological universe are you using _complement_ and _adjunct_ in? There are a number of possible uses, in different theories, for both terms; they don't always contrast, for sure.

Answer (score 1):

"Eager readers" is simply the object of the prepositional phrase "to the author's eager readers." I would say that both that phrase, and the adverb "immediately" are adjuncts. Neither is necessary for the sentence to be grammatically complete.